# Node-ews Bearer get Email nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exchangewebservices, node-ews

im getting problem when i try to get email from EWS
i have a

```
class EWSModule {
    async test(token, mailID){
        const ewsConfig = {
            token,
            host: 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',
            auth: 'bearer',
            username: 'Dont Known Why This Need This'
        };
        
        let ews = new EWS(ewsConfig);
        console.log(await this.getItem({id:mailID},ews))
    }

   async  getItem (item, ews){
        const ewsFunction = 'GetItem';
    
        const ewsArgs = {
          'ItemShape': {
            'BaseShape': 'Default',
            'IncludeMimeContent':'true'
          },
          "ItemIds" : {
            "ItemId" : {
                "attributes": {
                   "Id" : item.Id
                }
              },
          }
        };
        return await ews.run(ewsFunction, ewsArgs)
    }
}
```

field username on ewsConfig is not used but its required.

When im doing this i get an error:

```
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: no auth mechanism defined
    at Auth.onRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/node_modules/request/lib/auth.js:132:32)
    at Request.auth (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/node_modules/request/request.js:1341:14)
    at Request.init (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/node_modules/request/request.js:378:10)
    at new Request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
    at request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/lib/auth/bearer.js:31:11
    at init (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:39:5)
    at new Promise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:27:53)
    at Function.promise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/when.js:97:10)
    at Object.getUrl (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/lib/auth/bearer.js:30:21)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/lib/ews.js:157:33
    at tryCatchReject (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:845:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:804:4)
    at Rejected.when (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:625:4)
    at Pending.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:483:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/usr/src/app/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)
```

Im dont known what im doing wrong to authenticate and did rest of my code (getting email) is correct

@GlenScales u are right :) i not passing token as undefined.
but this not solved my problem completly.

not i got an:

```
(node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid or malformed wsdl file: /tmp/tmp-19GjJa1cZki3Xp/services.wsdl
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-ews/lib/ews.js:126:20
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:73:3)
```

all files:
[image]
are empty

Comment: If you run it in debug what does ewsConfig end up looking like, because of the way you passing in the Token it maybe the result is not quite what you or the code is expecting, it should be pretty obvious if you look at the object and properties in debug.

Comment: @GlenScales im adding next part to my question

Comment: Why don't you use Graph API for Office365 accounts? The REST API is easier than EWS.

Also check out Aurinko's Unified Email API, it could simplify a few things for you:
https://docs.aurinko.io/article/18-email-api

Answer (score 0):

I think your config for host is wrong eg in the source code its doing

```
  // build ews url
  ews.urlApi = ews.config.host + '/EWS/Exchange.asmx';

  // build ews soap urls
  ews.urlServices = ews.config.host + '/ews/services.wsdl';
  ews.urlMessages = ews.config.host + '/ews/messages.xsd';
  ews.urlTypes = ews.config.host + '/ews/types.xsd';
```

so your config for the host should just be

```
const ewsConfig = {
 host: 'https://outlook.office365.com'

};
```

Comment: Its seems connect to EWS :) how can i now get an email?

Using my function im get an info: `{"ResponseMessages":{"GetItemResponseMessage":{"attributes":{"ResponseClass":"Error"},"MessageText":"Id is malformed.","ResponseCode":"ErrorInvalidIdMalformed","DescriptiveLinkKey":0,"Items":null}}}`

Comment: the error is saying the Id your passing in isn't a valid ewsid

Comment: im getting id from outlook Plugin by:
`serviceRequest.mailId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;`

Comment: What does the value look like ? In compose mode that value can be null so if maybe you passing it as undefined.

Comment: no its not undefined its looks like good id

Comment: if you compare it against what you see in the ewsEditor is it the same ? it maybe you getting the RESTid rather then the EWS one if you can post the value its easy to to say what it is.